# How do I get the bonus treasure in the Mirro Shaz shrine?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

The Mirro Shaz shrine is fairly straightforward; you walk in, there is a ball tee'd up in the middle of the room, and a chest with a sledgehammer. Use Stasis on the ball, swing a few times with the hammer, bing bang boom, this golf game is over and the door opens when the ball lands in the hole on the other side of the wall.

Simple enough.

But where's the bonus treasure!?!? Every shrine has bonus treasure, and a simple iron sledgehammer required to solve the puzzle surely isn't it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you approach the altar to 'complete' the shrine, you'll notice that there's actually another path around the back to the left.

If you follow this path, you'll come to an elevator that leads down to a mirror of the first room. Same tee, another sledgehammer, and a door with a chest behind it.

But this time, the golf shot is far less forgiving. There are pillars obstructing all but the straightest of shots, and the hole doesn't have a large platform leading up to it to provide the relatively forgiving shot of the first tee. In order to land the shot at the exact distance, you'll need to hit it **four times with the sledgehammer and then twice more with a one-handed weapon** while under stasis. And it needs to be perfectly straight.

Good luck!

Comment: I found it easier to just charge the hammer and the spins will hit it as many times until max (so no need to count). And you didn't need to hit it from the "tee" spot, you could move the starting position anywhere on the platform. I just moved it back a bit so a max shot would just land in. Took a couple of tries because it's hard to get a straight shot. You should be able to hit it at an angle too, but I think it was a lot tougher.

Comment: If you have a screenshot of the spot you moved the orb to (or just can count tiles or something), this would make a great alternative answer.

Comment: IIRC, I was hitting it just forward of the center of the perpendicular path to the chest. Like right on the crack of it. But it's been so long since I did that shrine that I don't remember the exact spot.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answer, another way to solve this bonus treasure puzzle is to just pick up the ball and move it backwards. This way you can adjust your distance a bit better. I moved the ball to be right next to the back wall, then it took 6 hits with the sledgehammer to send it into the goal.

The reward for this bonus section is

> a Giant Ancient Core

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solutions provided here and resorted to looking at some playthrough videos in the end. The bottom line for me was: Everybody does it differently. Still, I will provide my solution in a seperate answer:

1. Line up with the ball, don't move it. You should stand straight in front of it with the "handle" of the Sheikah eye (the arch over the hole) seen inside the dent of the pillar.
2. Use stasis.
3. Target the ball with `ZL` and hit it 5 times.
4. Hit it with a one-handed weapon 1 time. Note: I am not sure how the damage affects the hit distance. I used a one-handed sword with ~30 dmg, a broad sword if I recall correctly.
5. The ball should bounce once before the platform, then into the circle and roll into the hole.

The most important part, of course, is aim. The biggest problem for me was the perspective change when using stasis. If you find yourself aiming in the wrong direction after stasis, don't waste the hits and weapon durability.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't target balls and things like that, you can only target monsters and npcs, but im not sure.